# Import svg as component using preact and vite

Tags: reactjs, svg, vite, preact

I'm currently working on an application using preact, tailwindcss and vite. Unfortunately, importing svgs seems to be a bit problematic.
There is a separate repository that only contains the svg resources.
My original plan was to just import them as components as I was used to do it in classic react with webpack applications using SVGR and the following syntax:

```
import { ReactComponent as Search } from 'assets/icons/search-lg.svg';
```

This won't work for (at least) two reasons. One being preact the other one being the lack of SVGR.
I then proceeded to give [vite-plugin-svgr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@honkhonk/vite-plugin-svgr) a try by importing it in my `vite.config.js`.

```
  plugins: [svgr({ svgrOptions: { jsxRuntime: 'classic-preact' } }), preact(), tsconfigPaths()],
```

It *kinda* works using the following import syntax:

```
import Search from 'assets/icons/search-lg.svg?component';
```

Unfortunately this raises the following error which I couldn't manage to work around besides ignoring it which is not really an option:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module 'assets/icons/search-lg.svg?component' or its corresponding type declarations
```

The alternate plan would now be to create a wrapper component that just imports the svg from the given path and create a component from it myself. This would also simplify styling it with tailwind.
Unfortunately I fail to import the file in a way I can wrap it with `<svg>` tags. Using `<img>` is not really an option because I need to be able to manipulate the svg.

So, does anybody have an idea how to either

- correctly use the component import in my setup
- create a preact component that imports an svg from a file and still is customizable

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about this plugin https://github.com/pd4d10/vite-plugin-svgr? Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qk88v1

Comment: @qk88v1 the plugin I used was a fork of the one you linked I think. I tried yours and found the issue I guess. I was missing `/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />` in vite-env.d.ts.
Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it to work by using [vite-plugin-svgr](https://github.com/pd4d10/vite-plugin-svgr). In the end adding `/// <reference types="vite-plugin-svgr/client" />` to `vite-env.d.ts` made the compiler happy.

I can now use the good 'ol syntax:

```
import { ReactComponent as Search } from 'assets/icons/search-lg.svg';
```

Thanks to @user-28 for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: FWIW, `svgr` is a really, really poor way to use SVGs and it should be avoided if at all possible. See https://twitter.com/_developit/status/1382838799420514317

Comment: Interesting, thank you! What alternative would you choose given that it should be possible to manipulate the svg with tailwind/css?

Comment: `<use>` is probably what you want: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use